# How do I fix this syntax error caused by a colon?

Tags: python

I'm creating a class that simulates an ATM and I don't know why I'm getting a syntax error on the colon between 'id' and 'zwhite'.

```
import pickle
import sys
import os

class ATM(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.users = ['id':'zwhite','name':'Zack White','pin':'4431','balance':845,
                      'id':'jzimmerman','name':'John Zimmerman','pin':'6780','balance':59,
                      'id':'cbenson','Carly Benson','pin':'8991','balance':720]

    def check(self,ids):
        print Your balance: +str(ids['balance'])
    def withdraw(self,person):
        for i in self.users:
            if i['id'] == person['id']:
                print Your balance: +str(i['balance'])
```

Comment: That syntax is for dictionaries. There are several other issues in your code, such as `'Carly Benson'` not having its key, and `print Your balance: ...`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm new to python so I'm not really sure what to do about the colon. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's unrelated to the `self.users` related error you're asking about, but your later code uses `print` statements that haven't been a thing since Python 2. To make this code work in Python 3 (as you have tagged it), you'll need to use `print()` as a function. There are also other errors, like missing quotation marks around strings you want to print....

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to be creating a list of dictionaries. This would make sense of the duplicated keys on separate lines:

Try:

```
    self.users = [{'id':'zwhite','name':'Zack White','pin':'4431','balance':845},
                  {'id':'jzimmerman','name':'John Zimmerman','pin':'6780','balance':59},
                  {'id':'cbenson','name':'Carly Benson','pin':'8991','balance':720}]
```

I also added the `'name'` key for the value `'Carly Benson'` in the last row.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary, not a list.

```
self.users = {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets ([ ]) are used to create a list. List are used to store elements only. You cannot store keys and values. You can just store elements like [1,2,3,"ab","cd",3.23] etc. If you want to store the data in key-value pairs, then you'll have to use dictionary. By looking at the code, I think you know the concept of dictionary but you're confused with creating dictionary. Curly braces ({ }) are used to create dictionary. Just change the square brackets to curly braces